# How do I get allowed Media Library upload file extension list?

Tags: uploads, media, media-library

WordPress has list of allowed Media Library upload extensions in wp-includes/functions.php but is there any way to return them to theme's files as an array?

Comment: Are you using multisite?

Comment: No. But an option to have both WP and WPMU solutions as an answer to this question would be great :)

Answer (score 2):

[get_allowed_mime_types()](http://queryposts.com/function/get_allowed_mime_types/) function returns an array of mime types keyed by the file extension regex corresponding to those types.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the [`wp_get_mime_types()`](http://wpseek.com/wp_get_mime_types) function

Comment: This function is introduced in WP3.5 and is not available in current stable release 3.4.x.

Comment: @Parham Thanks - I wasn't aware of this. Do you know if this function will be preferred over `get_allowed_mime_types()` when 3.5 is released?

Comment: according to the source code, wp_get_mime_types() returns the list of ALL mime types and applies the 'mime_types' filter on the list. The filter should be used to add types, not remove them.
get_allowed_mime_types() returns a list of allowed mime types, it uses wp_get_mime_types() to fetch the list but applies one more filter: 'upload_mimes' which can be used to remove types.